# MATLAB R2016a Remote Desktop Error - License Manager Error -103 - How to Fix?

Tags: matlab, remote-desktop

There is a problem in 2016a to be used through remote desktop software. I had used MATLAB 2015a through remote desktop successfully. However, in 2016a (and 2016b) there is an error when running MATLAB (License Manager Error -103). How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What type of license system did you use?

Comment: I have activated matlab by a "license_standalone" file for 2016a.

Comment: Note that [remote desktop is not supported](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91874-why-do-i-receive-license-manager-error-103).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is this a feature only in 2016 versions?

Answer (score 1):

The ability of running MATLAB in RDP (Remote Desktop Connection) depends on the License of your installation.

See [Is It Possible to Use MATLAB Over Remote Desktop Software?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93963-is-it-possible-to-use-matlab-over-remote-desktop-software)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem over matlab 2017b. I used Teamviewer instead of remote desktop, It worked for me.